# Selector for menu item in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm creating app with toolbar with menu how I can set selector for menu items or change bg color when I do click on them?

my code:
themes

```
<style name="Theme.Toolbar"  parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar_Popup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</style>


<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar in Activity layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Toolbar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar_Popup"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbar_bg_color" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: did you find a way to solve this?